# list indexing vs copying

Tags: python, list

I have a list named `mylist`

What is the difference between

`newlist = mylist`

and

`newlist = mylist[:]`

it would seem that the latter is safer to use as it will not mutate `mylist` based on any manipulation of `newlist`

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first only creates another name for the list. It is still the same list.

This means mutating `newlist` also mutates `mylist`.

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> newlist = mylist
>>> newlist.append(4)
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The second example actually creates a copy of the list, an actual new list.

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> newlist = mylist[:]
>>> newlist.append(4)
>>> newlist
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> mylist
[1, 2, 3]
```

You have little reason to have two names for the same object as this can be both confusing and lead to mutation bugs.

A mutation bug is when some object is needed in some part of your code, say a function `func1`, but mutated beforehand by some other part of your code, say a function `func2`. If the object in its initial state was expected by `func1`, it can be very tedious to track down where the mutation happened.

Example:

```
obj = [list of data]
same_obj = obj

func2(same_obj) # mutates the object

# hundreds of lines of code

func1(obj) # needs the initial state of the object
```

In the above example, it would have been better to pass `func2` a copy of `obj`. Since a lot happen between the first and last lines, it can be very tedious to track down the mutation bug.